# Is it possible to spoof IP behind NAT?

Tags: ip, nat, spoof

Is it possible to spoof the source IP if I'm behind a router that is using NAT?

If not, how do botnet programmers manage to make a SYN flood from their slaves? Don't most home/business networks use NAT?

Answer (score 2):

In short, No unless you have a leak in the protocol.

A botnet can still "do a SYN flood" but, in case where a NAT function delineates the corporate LAN from the Internet, it is the router that will get flooded.

Of course, the actual situation is more complicated than that but I won't get into fully describing it here.